# He-initialization for Caffe?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I know that I can either initialize the weights of a convolutional network in caffe with `xavier` or `gaussian`. Sadly I can not find any other initialization methods implemented in caffe. Especially, I would like to use the PReLU initialization as suggested in this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.01852.pdf

Is this shomewho implemented in caffe and pycaffe?

Comment: I would rather say "He initialization" than "PRelu initialization" as "PRelu" is the activation function.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **MSRA** (for Microsoft Research Asia) filler was implemented in Caffe a few months after the paper was released. You can use it with the `msra` parameter.

[See the documentation for more information.](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/doxygen/classcaffe_1_1MSRAFiller.html#details)

Answer (score 4):

He et al use an initialization scheme which samples each weight w of a given layer independantly identically distributed (iid):

[image]

However, you might know that Var(aX) = a^2 Var(X). Hence:

[image]

So you can simply initialize the weights with `gaussian` and then multiply them with `2 / n_l`.

Comment: I having a little trouble here and you seem very advanced in it. How can I know n_l ?

Comment: `n_l` is the number of connections of layer `l` as explained in the paper in section 2.2 (below equation 5). So if layer `l-1` has `c` filters and layer `l` has filters of size `a*b`, then `n_l = c*a*b`.

Comment: See also https://github.com/Lasagne/Lasagne/blob/master/lasagne/init.py#L198 if you want to see the implementation of Lasagne.